# ReactJS state depending on another state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a component that have an object state, where one of the properties is basically another state, something like this:

```
this.state = {
stateNameList : [],
fieldProperties = 
        [
            { type: FieldType.ComboBox, label: "State", fieldId: "state", source:this.state.stateNameList }
}
```

Is there a way to do it? Because that stateNameList will be populated on the componentWillMount function, by calling an API service.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to initialize an empty array in initial state, then populate it with data from an API call when the component mounts.

Comment: but when I do that on initial state, I get an error saying that this.state is undifined, on the "source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the state based on the state, you have to create `this.state` **first**, and then add new keys based on the already created object. Something like that:

```
this.state = {
    stateNameList : [],
    fieldProperties: []
}

this.state.fieldProperties.push(
    { 
        type: FieldType.ComboBox, 
        label: "State", 
        fieldId: "state", 
        source: this.state.stateNameList //now it knows what this.state is
    }
)
```

Besides this, you were setting `fieldProperties` value with `=` operator, and not `:`. And you were not closing the `fieldProperties` brackets.